# Formatting of Data Frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, merge, summarize

I have a data.frame with the following structure:

[image]

What I need is that in case that a value in the first column occures more than once, all corresponding entries in column V18 are concluded in one cell.
I applied the folling code.

```
p <- function(v) {
  Reduce(f=paste0, x = v)
}

Data %>% 
    group_by(V1) %>% 
    summarise(test = p(as.character(V18))) %>%
    merge(., M_TEST, by = 'V1') %>%
    select(V1, V18, test)
```

It gives:

[image]

What I need is that instead of 4344, it is {43,44}.
How can I do this?

Thank you really much for your help!

Sincerely

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways of showing data.

Comment: Something like this? `Data %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarize(V18 = paste(V18, collapse = ","))`

Comment: This is actually pretty good. Thank you @Jean-Claude Arbaut. That gives 43,44. What I need is {43,44}. Do you know if that is somehow possible as well?

Comment: Sure. `paste0("{", paste(V18, collapse=","), "}")`

Comment: You may also do `Data %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarize(V18 = list(V18))`. It's not exactly what you want, but it stores the grouped elements in an actual R list (of vectors). Can be handy in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  summarise(test = p(as.character(V18))) %>%
  merge(., M_TEST, by = 'V1') %>%
  select(V1, V18, test) %>% 
  mutate(test = str_remove_all(test, pattern = "NA")) %>% 
  mutate(test = formatC(as.numeric(test), big.mark=",", big.interval = 2L)) %>% 
  mutate(test = paste0("{", test, "}"))
```

Edit: For Multiple Columns, this should work:

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(V2:V18), paste0, collapse="") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(V2:V18), str_remove_all, pattern = "NA") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(V2:V18), as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(V2:V18), formatC, big.mark=",", big.interval = 2L)
```

Comment: Thank you @Mohanasundaram, I think this is very close! Instead of {43,44}, it gives {4,334}.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just overlooked. Added the big.interval argument. Check it now.

Comment: Do you know if this procedure is also possible for several column at once. So group_by(V1) remains, but there is not only V18 but all column from V2 to V18?

Comment: Check the edit. I've also made some changes in the first code.

Comment: Thank you! What can I do if the lenght of the number not always 2 but a mixture of 1 and 2? :(